# How to find table region for camelot

Tags: python-camelot

As mentioned in camelot, we can extract table from particular region like:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf('table_regions.pdf', table_regions=['170,370,560,270'])
```

But how can I find these regions for my pdf.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect this regions, by some visual debugging.

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#visual-debugging

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a late reply - but I just came across a possible solution.

If you're looking for a automated extraction method, you could use `lattice` in a first step, retrieve the table boundaries with `tables[0]._bbox` and use these numbers in a second call to `camelot.read_pdf()` into the argument `table_areas`.

Be aware that they are in a weirdly sorted format for a bbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect the table region you are reading, try to do this using Jupyter Notebook:

1. Define the table region inside `.read_pdf` method: `tables = camelot.read_pdf('table_regions.pdf', table_regions=['170,370,560,270'], flavor='lattice')`; pay attention on the flavor, because it defines whether the table have borderlines or not(it can be lattice for borders or stream for space).
2. Use camelot-py with plot from matplotlib: `camelot.plot(tables[index], kind='contour')` (You may know about how many index your object have by simply executing the name of the object. e.g.: `tables` runnign inside .ipynb cell)(contour is a visual debugging).
3. The plot will show an image of your table with a red rectangle contour. Just repeats step 2 until you achieve the table region you want to extract.
4. To test if the data is correct just use `tables[index].df`.

Comment: I can't figure out what the coordinates refer to. Are they corner points? edges of the box? There is no mention in the documentation of this.

Comment: There is a note in the documentation on Advanced Usage page that explains :
table_areas accepts strings of the form x1,y1,x2,y2 where (x1, y1) -> top-left and (x2, y2) -> bottom-right in PDF coordinate space. In PDF coordinate space, the bottom-left corner of the page is the origin, with coordinates (0, 0)